# Passing extras from ANE to Flex app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex-mobile

I have a flex mobile application with an ANE. This ANE has a broadcast receiver that starts the flex mobile application when it receives an event:

```
public class BroadcastEventHandler extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "BROADCAST EVENT RECEIVED!");      
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, 
                       Class.forName(context.getPackageName()+".AppEntry"));

        i.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("nameKey", "value");
        context.startActivity(i);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error on starting Intent: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

On the flex application I have the following code:

```
protected function view1_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(
    InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
}

private function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void
{
    trace("Arguments: " + event.arguments);
}
```

What I want to do is to pass Extras from the broadcastreceiver to the flex application when it is executed (as you can see I added a Bundle object in the ANE code, but I don't receive anything in the flex application):

Trace:

```
Arguments:
```

Do you know a way to start activity (in android native) with some parameters/extras and get them in the flex application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could not do this via Bundle object from native code. Passing arguments to an application must be with the `<data android:scheme="my-scheme"/>` tag in the manifest.
However,

> One caveat is that invoking other apps with the custom URL schemes from AIR apps is not possible. The AIR security model is more restrictive and it limits schemes to: http:, https:, sms:, tel:, mailto:, file:, app:, app-storage:, vipaccess: and connectpro:. You can find more about it here and here.

From this great tutorial:

http://www.riaspace.com/2011/08/defining-custom-url-schemes-for-your-air-mobile-applications/

So far, what I have done is implement a class with member data. There, I store the data that I want to handle later  (which is the same data that I wanted to pass directly via the Bundle).

```
public class DataModel {
  //data I will get after in the actionscript side of the code
  private int notificationCode;

  public int getNotificationCode(){
    return notificationCode;
  }

  public void setNotificationCode(int notificationCode){
    this.notificationCode=notificationCode;
  }
}
```

When I receive a notification in the broadcastreceiver I set the new value of the notificationCode, and then I start the activity (same as before but adding a call to setNotificationCode function).

Then, in the actionscript side, on the method onInvoke, I do the following call:

```
//call native functions:
//broadcastevent is the EventDispatcher that connects to the ANE
notificationCode=broadcastevent.getCode();

switch(notificationCode)
{
 case Constants.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_CODE:
 {
     notificationMessage="THERE ARE NO NOTIFICATIONS";
     break;
 }
 case Constants.UPDATE_APP_CODE:
 {
     notificationMessage="UPDATE APP NOTIFICATION";
     break;
 }  
 case Constants.SHOW_ALERT_CODE:
 {
     notificationMessage="SHOW ALERT NOTIFICATION";
     break;
 }  
 default:
         break;
```

It is not what I exactly was looking for but I have not found other way to do something similar, and it works!